# How to split a string at 2 or more consecutive spaces in PHP

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-split

I finally have a question that isn't already answered on Stack Overflow for PHP.

I need to save the city, state, zip in different variables. Given the string

```
$new = "PALM DESERT             SD63376        "
```

I am trying to strip spaces that are grouped in 2 or more so I can keep a city 2 words when it is supposed to be. Beyond that I can figure out but all my searching either shows how to split a string in a different language (Java), or how to split at one space which I cannot do.

I'm trying to use

```
$addr = preg_split('#^.*(?=\s{2, })#', $new);
```

but I am not getting the string split between `PALM DESERT` AND "SD63376       ". Please help!

Comment: What about one word cities? How are they going to be handled? Why is this in one string? Can you break it apart before it gets to this point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559363/matching-a-space-in-regex This might help

Comment: unfortunately no, its what is passed into php from mysql. Its from an outside source

Comment: The Zerg are evolving regexes?!? Now we have more than two problems...

Comment: What about simply `preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $new)`? [It seems to work fine](http://ideone.com/M9vPTt).

Comment: I had tried that earlier but for some reason it didn't work, but then when I tried it after you suggested it, it decides to work :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$str = "PALM DESERT             SD63376        ";
// note that there are two spaces in the regex pattern
var_dump(preg_split('~  +~', $str, -1,  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(11) "PALM DESERT"
  [1] =>
  string(7) "SD63376"
}
```

Comment: The OP wants "PALM" and "DESERT" to remain together.

Comment: Ou! I didn't realized this. Give me a second

Comment: What does the tilde do? I've never seen that