# Add spacebar in regular expression

Tags: regex

I use this regular expression for checking

```
public const string FullNameRegularExpression = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$";
```

How to add "spacebar" in?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for one single space it is:  (`" "`), a very complete example can be found [in this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559363/matching-a-space-in-regex).

Or if you want to match any whitespace character (`\n`,`\r`,`\f`,`\t`, ), you can use `\s`.

Comment: you should make op aware of what `\s` would actually match as compared to literal space

Answer (score 0):

Notice an added `\s`

```
public const string FullNameRegularExpression = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9._-\s]+$";
```

Comment: that would also match \n,\r,\f,\t..OP needs to match only space!..

Comment: @Anirudh: That is not an issue here as you'll not have tab or newline etc in a filename anyways ;-)

Comment: @Artur Then why use a selector that matches them?

Comment: @Juhana: why use a dot in a regex to match anything then? ;-)

Comment: @Artur: You got that wrong with the dot. See my comment to your answer.

Comment: @Artur That's really not the same thing, is it? If you have a filename that's *guaranteed* to not contain any other whitespace than space, there's no reason to use any other selector than the space character. But there are valid reasons to use `.` to match everything instead of typing out each possibility (which would be somewhere around a hundred in case of ASCII filenames, not to mention Unicode strings).

Comment: People, please realize: The dot *inside a character expression* does **not** match everything. It matches a dot. Nothing more.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I thought we were talking about a general case, not this regex specifically.

Answer (score -1):

You may push a spacebar on your keyboard or add \s or \s+ or \s* to your regex ;-)

Comment: that would also match \n,\r,\f,\t..OP needs to match only space!..

Comment: @Anirudh Not if you push spacebar....

Comment: *"To match a dot use \."* Inside a character expression you don't need to escape the dot.

Comment: @Daniel: Indeed and there dot means literal dot. Thanks Daniel