# Ignore spaces in Regex

Tags: php, regex

how to capture with regex everything but spaces

For example I have `Hello Word`

What regex to use to output `HelloWord`

(I'm using Regex and php)
Best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching a space in regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559363/matching-a-space-in-regex)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str)
```

Comment: Almost. Change it to: `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);` (PHP does not have a `preg_replace_all()` function. And `\s` need not be in a character class.)

Comment: Also the space is actually `[ ]`, you've answered for whitespace (which probably OP has been looking for), perhaps with UTF-8 encoded input?

Comment: In that case, the OP might want to use `\p{Z}` or `\p{Zs}`.

Comment: It will not be possible to do it just with Regex and without using php?

Comment: you need some language anyway, Regex just a feature of language

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = "Hello Word";
$string = preg_replace('/ /', '', $string);
echo $string;
//HelloWord
?>
```

http://ideone.com/RvYkdA