# Hashtag word must start with a space

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
/#([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/g
```

http://regexr.com/393bh

How can I make it so that there *must* be a space before the hashtag for the regex to be valid (i.e. the second line in the link above shouldn't match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a space in your regex as follows:

```
/ #([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/g
```

To not include the space in the match, you can do:

```
/(?:\s)(#[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/g
```

Comment: How would I make it not include the space in the match?

Comment: @user3769178, Answer updated (second regex). Now if you use that regex, the ___first captured group___ will not contain the space.

Answer (score 2):

From:

```
/#([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/
```

To:

```
/\s#([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/
```

More information on matching space/s: [Matching a space in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559363/matching-a-space-in-regex#answer-559404)

http://jsfiddle.net/PeV57/

Comment: Okay, how do I make it not include the space though?

Comment: @user3769178: Well the hash-tag part is between brackets, you can use regex capturing techniques for this. Every programming language has some kind of api for this (but you didn't specify your environment).

Answer (score 1):

Use \K or look behind to not to include space at the end result.

```
/ \K#([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/g
```

OR

```
(?<=\s)#([A-Za-z0-9_]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rJ6gZ3/4)

First captured group contains the string `test`. If you want the captured group to contain `#`, the use this regex `(?<=\s)(#[A-Za-z0-9_]+)`

Comment: Why would this make any difference? Your regex matches strictly the same set of strings. Since the space is optional at the beginning, the regex can simply ignore this.

Comment: @CommuSoft what do you mean?

Comment: looks like support may be an issue using `\K` ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex

Comment: yep, op doesn't mention the language.