# Treat every whitespaces as the same character in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I made a regex to highlight keywords found in a text by another tool.

```
new RegExp(highlightedKeywords.map(v => `\\b${v}\\b`).join('|') || /.^/, 'gi'), match => `<mark>${match}</mark>`)
```

I would like to make this regex treat every whitespaces as the same because the tool who extract keywords from the text convert every whitespace as space, so for example I have a keyword "the cat" not found because the actual text is "the\ncat".

I don't want to ignore whitespaces because "the cat" should not match "thecat" but I would like to match "the\tcat" or even "the\n \tcat"

Comment: You're looking for `\s`.

Comment: But you may want to provide sample data for `highlightedkeywords` and desired output for others to give you stronger feedback on the best approach for you.

Comment: Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236101/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

Answer found thanks to pwilcox : "You're looking for \s"

```
new RegExp(highlightedKeywords.map(v => `\\b${v.replace(/\s/g, '\\s')}\\b`).join('|') || /.^/, 'gi')`
```

I replace every whitespace in the keywords by \s